# Compute running time function

Tags: algorithm

I have a method and I want to compute its running time:

```
print()
{
node* p1 = sentinel_->next_;
while(p1 != sentinel_)
cout << p1->data_ << “ “;
p1 = p1->next_;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

If I assumed the `while` loop can be executed **n-1** times. 
So:
**T(n) = 1 + (n-1) + (n-1) + (n-1) + 1 = 3n - 1.** 
But what is the correct value to use for the “input size,” N?
Is it gonna be based on the **T(n)** 
Which is **3n - 1 >= 0 so n >= 1/3**
Or **n** simply just **greater or equal** to 1 
since the while loop can at least be executed one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithmic complexity is usually calculated in terms of asymptotic notation. What this means is how the algorithm behaves as the size of the input varies.

For your example, "n" could be anything. If n == 2, your while loop will run once, if n == 3, your while loop runs twice...In general, as you mentioned the while loop runs "n-1" number of times for a given value of "n". This means as the value of "n" increases, your while loop will take longer to run. Thus, the complexity of your algorithm is directly determined by the number of times the loop is run. And the number of times the loop is run is determined by the value of "n". Thus, your code has a running complexity of O(n).

Let's say you have a method where you first traverse the list and add 10 to each node value. Then, you again traverse the list to print each node value. This algorithm will have a running complexity of O(n) + O(n) = 2 * O(n). This still equates to O(n) runtime since constants are ignored. Again, this is just theoretically. Practically, you are looping over the list twice which is going to make the program slower.

I hope I am clear in my explanation. I am not using any technical terms but I hope you get the point.

Comment: So you said "n" could be anything, and if n == 2 the while loop will run once. But is n possible to be 1 or less than 1? . Since I am thinking the while loop at least could be executed once.